# JQ: Combine array with a list of objects from another file

Tags: json, bash, jq

I need to append content in my primary file with information from a secondary file.

The primary file looks like this one:

```
[
  {
    "dynamic-parent-key-1": {
      "key1": "value1",
      "key2": "value2",
      "array1": [
        "array-value-1",
        "array-value-2"
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "dynamic-parent-key-2": {
      "key1": "value1",
      "key2": "value2",
      "array1": [
        "array-value-1"
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

And the secondary file looks like this one:

```
{
  "fixedKey": [
    {
      "Key": "A",
      "Value": "abc"
    },
    {
      "Key": "B",
      "Value": "xyz"
    },
    {
      "Key": "C",
      "Value": "asd"
    }
  ]
}
{
  "fixedKey": [
    {
      "Key": "A",
      "Value": "aaa"
    },
    {
      "Key": "B",
      "Value": "bbb"
    },
    {
      "Key": "C",
      "Value": "ccc"
    }
  ]
}
```

The elements order is related. The first object "fixedKey" corresponds to "dynamic-parent-key-1" and so on. The first file is JSON compliant and the second is not, it is just a list of JSON objects saved on a common file.

I need an output file (or just update the first one) so it looks ideally like this:

```
{
  "master-key": {
    "dynamic-parent-key-1": {
      "key1": "value1",
      "key2": "value2",
      "array1": [
        "array-value-1",
        "array-value-2"
      ],
      "fixedKey": [
        {
          "Key": "A",
          "Value": "abc"
        },
        {
          "Key": "B",
          "Value": "xyz"
        },
        {
          "Key": "C",
          "Value": "asd"
        }
      ]
    },
    "dynamic-parent-key-2": {
      "key1": "value1",
      "key2": "value2",
      "array1": [
        "array-value-1"
      ],
      "fixedKey": [
        {
          "Key": "A",
          "Value": "aaa"
        },
        {
          "Key": "B",
          "Value": "bbb"
        },
        {
          "Key": "C",
          "Value": "ccc"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

But if that is not possible or too complicated, I could stick to first file structure and obtain something like this:

```
[
  {
    "dynamic-parent-key-1": {
      "key1": "value1",
      "key2": "value2",
      "array1": [
        "array-value-1",
        "array-value-2"
      ],
      "fixedKey": [
        {
          "Key": "A",
          "Value": "abc"
        },
        {
          "Key": "B",
          "Value": "xyz"
        },
        {
          "Key": "C",
          "Value": "asd"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "dynamic-parent-key-2": {
      "key1": "value1",
      "key2": "value2",
      "array1": [
        "array-value-1"
      ],
      "fixedKey": [
        {
          "Key": "A",
          "Value": "aaa"
        },
        {
          "Key": "B",
          "Value": "bbb"
        },
        {
          "Key": "C",
          "Value": "ccc"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

How can I achieve this? I've been trying with map(), |=, + but I can't make it.
Should I first prepare my secondary file to be JSON compliant or it is not necessary?

Comment: your secondary file is a stream of perfectly compliant JSONs, no need pre-processing it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following script should work for you.

```
jq -n '{ "master-key": input | add | map_values(. + input) }' file1.json file2.json
```

The [`-n` (`--null-input`)](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Invokingjq) option disables the automatic read of input streams so that you can manually deal with each object (using functions like [`input` or `inputs`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#IO)). The first `input` call loads the array from your primary file and `add` converts this array to an object. Then `map_values` merges each sub-object with a new object loaded from the input stream (now on the secondary file) by subsequent `input` calls.

Comment: This works exactly as I expected. Thank you very much! Checking documentation to fully understand the script. Thanks again.